# Sensors and saving to variable

Tags: bash, sensors

I am trying to get two sensors and add both answers to variable in a `bash` script.

I got this but it is not suited to my needs.

```
[root@**** ~]# sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +40.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 1:       +45.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 2:       +50.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 8:       +47.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 9:       +48.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 10:      +45.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +36.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 1:       +44.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 2:       +41.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 8:       +42.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 9:       +44.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)
Core 10:      +48.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +96.0°C)


[root@*** ~]# sensors | sed -rn 's/.*Core 0:\s+.([0-9]+).*/\1/p'
40
36
```

I need 40 and 36 saved into variables. Is there anyway to add them in two separate variables in a `bash` script?

Comment: Maybe this gives you an idea  `var=$(awk '/Core 0:/{printf("%s ", $3+0)}' sensors )`

Answer (score 1):

You could also bypass the `sensors` command and read the values directly from the `/sys` filesystem:

```
VAR1RAW=$(cat /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon*/temp1_input)
VAR1=$(expr $VAR1RAW / 1000)
VAR2RAW=$(cat /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.1/hwmon/hwmon*/temp1_input)
VAR2=$(expr $VAR2RAW / 1000)
```

(The asterisk at the `hwmon*` path element allows us to ignore the hwmon device number: as we're coming in through the `.../platform/coretemp.N/...` route, there'll be just one matching directory at that level.)

The raw values in the `/sys` filesystem are expressed in thousandths of degrees, so you'll need to divide by 1000. Since `expr` only does integer arithmetic, that'll also drop out the decimals at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This all could be achieved using a simple awk one liner only. For example:

```
awk '/Core 0:/{i[$3+0];} END { n=1; for(a in i) printf("%s=%d\n", "var"n++,a)}'
```

- Match pattern `/Core 0/`
- Create an array variable `i[$3+0]`. The `+0` will strip everything after the digit
- Initialize variable `n` to `1` as in: `n=1`. Loop trough indices and print the results by incrementing variable `n`.

> NOTE! By convention, environment variables (PATH, EDITOR, SHELL, ...) and internal shell variables (BASH_VERSION, RANDOM, ...) are fully capitalized. All other variable names should be lowercase. Since variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
VAR=$(sensors | sed -rn 's/.*Core 0:\s+.([0-9]+).*/\1/p'|tr '\n' ' ')
```

This will replace newline with space and add both values to the `VAR` variable. If you want to separate them in two variables you can use the code below (I know its not optimal, but work for me)

```
VAR1=$(echo $VAR|awk '{print $1}')
VAR2=$(echo $VAR|awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: is there a way to sperate the vars like VAR1=36 and VAR2=40

Comment: @Wayno, please check my edited answer

Comment: really that easy, lol i was racking my brain over it, Thank you for your time.